# new Error() - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Not Found

Tags: javascript, service-worker

The error is `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Not Found.` 
This seems to be due to the window not being available inside self. Self is either service worker or window.

The code below is in index.html and everything is working fine. When a network request returns 404 it evaluates `throwOnError` and this error appears.

```
var throwOnError = (response) => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300 || response.status === 0) {
      return response;
  }
  throw new Error(response.statusText);
};

function cacheableRequestFailingToCacheStrategy({ event, cache }) {
  return fetch(event.request)
    .then(throwOnError) // do not cache errors
    .then(response => {
      cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
      return response;
    })
    .catch(() => cache.match(event.request));
}

function isRequestForStatic(request) {
  return /.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js)$/.test(request.url);
}

function isSideEffectRequest(request) {
  console.log(request.method);
  return ["POST", "PUT", "DELETE"].includes(request.method);
}

function cacheFailingToCacheableRequestStrategy({ event, cache }) {
  return cache.match(event.request)
    .then(throwOnError)
    .catch(() => fetch(event.request)
      .then(throwOnError)
      .then(response => {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
      })
    );
}

function requestFailingWithNotFoundStrategy({ event }) {
  return fetch(event.request)
    .catch(() => {
      const body = JSON.stringify({ error: "Sorry, you are offline. Please, try later." });
      const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
      const response = new Response(body, { status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", headers });
      return response;
    });
}

self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  console.log(event.request);
  if (isSideEffectRequest(event.request)) {
    console.log("post", event.request.method);
    event.respondWith(requestFailingWithNotFoundStrategy({ event }));
    return;
  }

  if (isRequestForStatic(event.request)) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
        .then(cache => cacheFailingToCacheableRequestStrategy({ event, cache }))
    );
    return;
  }

  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(cache => cacheableRequestFailingToCacheStrategy({ event, cache }))
  );
});
```

Comment: The code looks to me like it's for a service worker, but you say "Below code is in index.html". Could you clarify?

Comment: Also: since you have code there that actually generates the "Not Found", and throws `Error` objects, what is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: Firstly - This is service worker ... but I haven't kept it in seperate sw.js file.. It is in index.html for global scope of service worker.

Comment: Second- Code should generate an error but the cunstroctur new ERROR is not defined in throwOnError method.

Comment: See my comment below on my answer: the Error class is standard JS.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of real clarity on the expected behaviour, I must assume the questioner wants to handle 404 errors without throwing exceptions.

One option is this (disclosure: it's written by me), a turnkey service worker that has cache-only, network-first, cache-first and network-only strategies, and does not throw errors on 404: https://github.com/mohawk2/sw-turnkey

Comment: Yes I want to handle error. But I can't throw error.  as new Error is not available inside service worker self. I will look into your solution

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error the Error is standard JS since ECMA 1. I am sure it actually is available, and the "Not Found" is from your own code.